# When turning on computer do I have to open my Monerod folder from my files for my GUI wallet to be able to sync or can I just open the GUI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod

I have win10, downloaded the GUI and the blockchain into my laptop. Finally got a full node running, even able to mine from the GUI now if I want to! Point is, everything is finally working and working great. But the whole time it was working, I did have the Monerod file open and I could keep looking in it to see progress and things like that before I got fully synced for the very first time. I left GUI on all night mining and this morning I shut it all down before I left for work. Shutdown the GUI, the monerod file I had open and the laptop. When I get home tonight, do I just turn on my laptop and open the GUI wallet I have as a shortcut on my desktop? Or, do I also have to open that monerod file as well and leave it running the whole time for the GUI wallet to sync and to stay synced. I hope you can understand what I'm asking, THANKS!

Comment: Works either way. You can start `monerod` separately or let the GUI start it automatically.

Comment: Thanks!. I ask because I start from turning on laptop>open GUI from my shortcut, immediately says starting daemon unless I want use custom settings. I do nothing wrh that suggestion, wait few more seconds and it proceeds to start daemon. After 2 mins a new screen pops up always saying Daemon Failed to Start, under that says "Timed out, local node not responding after 120 seconds. Please check your wallet and daemon log for errors. You can also try to start monerod.exe manually".-So I open files, open monerod and it all starts up fine. I wish didnt have to open my files>monerod to make it work?

Comment: Something is wrong? It always works once I open files and go to GUI package downloaded then open monerod. Have to leave it running. Only thing weird I noticed is the address location shown on settings>node is different than the addresses shown on the settings>info>wallet path and wallet log path. Those two are also different from each other, and diff from the node address. 3 addresses!LoL  I did download the GUI twice. I tried to start over one time a week after the 1st time because I thought I did something wrong 1st time. I prob got a mess! But, it does work(sort of). I can mine now! haha!

Comment: Does the GUI properly connect to the daemon (monerod) if it runs separately? '3 addresses!LoL' <= That is expected.

Comment: No sir. I click on GUI and does not connect to daemon, monerod, unless I physically go into my yellow folder icon at bottom of screen(windows 10), open that, go into my big folder with all my monero files, go to my "monerod" file from there and click "open". Then, from there the GUI will sync after a few mins, you know, whatever I'm behind at that point in my monerod. Takes like 5 to 10+ mins or so. Then I can send monero or mine or whatever I desire at that point. I remember I tried to delete everything from 1st download, then downloaded everything again one day. I got stuff from then still

Comment: I got stuff from that 1st download still on compter. I can tell because those things have the Jan 7 date, and the 2nd download stuff has the March 6 date. So I still got stuff from that 1st one! But, because I funally got everything to work right(sort of), I didn't want to start deleting things that say Jan 7. I got like 2 big folders and in those I got a monerod with Jan 7, and in other folder got monerod with March 6. haha? So yes sir, prob got a mess but that actually works to use wallet, mine and other things.There are several folders that wont stay opened too! Weird. Sorry for trivial ?'s

Comment: What version numbers are ascribed to both those folders?

Comment: dEBRUYNE, you should probably add an answer with what's in your first comment, since it answers the actual question.